# Does without using @csrf on livewire component makes my form vulnerable?

Tags: laravel-livewire

Since I can use `wire:click` to submit a livewire component properties, why bother to use `<form>`?

Using the [document `ContactForm`](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/input-validation#real-time-validation) as a example.

```php
class ContactForm extends Component
{
    public $name;
    public $email;
 
    protected $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|min:6',
        'email' => 'required|email',
    ];
 
    public function updated($propertyName)
    {
        $this->validateOnly($propertyName);
    }
 
    public function saveContact()
    {
        $validatedData = $this->validate();
 
        Contact::create($validatedData);
    }
}
```

In the beginning, when I wrote a livewire form component, it look like this:(using `<form>` and `@csrf`)

```php
<form wire:submit.prevent="saveContact">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" wire:model="name">
    @error('name') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
 
    <input type="text" wire:model="email">
    @error('email') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
 
    <button type="submit">Save Contact</button>
</form>
```

But now, I write a form like this:(without `<form>` and without `@csrf`)

```php
<div>
    <input type="text" wire:model="name">
    @error('name') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
 
    <input type="text" wire:model="email">
    @error('email') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
 
    <button type="button" wire:click="saveContact">Save Contact</button>
</div>
```

- The document says that Livewire use a "checksum" to validate each request and response.
- It also say that Livewire re-apply every authentication/authorization middleware.

All my member-restricted forms require users to login before fill and submit forms. So those forms are under protection of `middleware('auth')` and livewire request/response checksum.

But without using `<form>` and `@csrf`, especially without `@csrf`, does it still makes my form more vulnerable? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [security documentation](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/security) for Livewire outlines how it's internal security is handled. This describes the usage of the "checksum", which ensures that the data between each request is not tampered with.

However it does not mention CSRF explicitly. None the less, since each subsequent Livewire request is a POST request to the `/livewire/message` endpoint, it must be protected with a CSRF token.

If we check the [source-code](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/blob/e117c78f9a4b19edb294b5b576138fd1f896925a/js/connection/index.js#L32), you'll see that it does indeed pass in the CSRF token. And since Livewire uses normal Laravel routes, it will by default validate the token in the backend - ensuring all requests are protected.

This means that when using any Livewire action such as `wire:click` or `wire:submit`, you don't have to worry about CSRF, as its handled by the framework.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's very detail and clear! I am relieved now.

Comment: The Livewire v3 versions of these things appear to be at:

https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/security#snapshot-checksums

and

https://github.com/livewire/livewire/blob/58e1716d43197b43fb22f71a9d1e7ea48bcc4bd1/js/request/index.js#L51